# Не работает route или Link React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

До авторизации нужно выбрать либо залогиниться, либо регистрироваться, первой формой появляется регистрация, но при переходе в форму авторизации появляется пустая страница, что я делаю не так?

Link в форме регистрации

```
 <Link to="/AuthPage">Sign In</Link>
```

Роуты

```
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <RegPage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <AuthPage />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

Comment: `<Route path="/AuthPage" exact>`

Comment: Спасибо, я че то не допер)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в том что ва используете `/` в двух узлах
Т.е

```
<Route path="/" exact>
<AuthPage />
</Route>
```

и

```
<Route path="/" exact>
<RegPage />
</Route>
```

Для AuthPage вы задумали `/AuthPage` а не `/`.
Просто замените `/` на `/AuthPage` в `<AuthPage />`

```
<Route path="/AuthPage" exact>
    <AuthPage />
</Route>
```